# Get timezone specific date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to calculate the time difference between two dates using moment-timezones but every time it it showing the same difference.

I am calculating the time like this:

```
const end_time = moment.tz(end_date, timezone);
const current_time = moment.tz(moment.tz.guess());
const difference = end_time - current_time;
let duration = moment.duration(difference, 'milliseconds');
```

I am getting the same duration no matter what timezone I set.

Can anybody suggest me how to get the correct difference using moment?

Comment: check your timezone format.  it's probably not one of the recognized formats  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones  https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/

Answer (score 0):

Use `diff` method, to check the duration differences between two objects

```js
var now = moment.tz("2020-05-14 00:00:00", "Europe/Berlin");
var end = moment.tz("2016-05-14 00:00:00", "Europe/Berlin");
var diff = now.diff(end);
console.log("diff is: " + diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```